# Keep current and previous line only if current line fulfills a given condition

Tags: awk

I have a file which looks like this:

```
>4RYF_1
MAENTKNENITNILTQKLIDTRTVLIYGEINQELAEDVSKQLLLLESISNDPITIFINSQGGHVEAGDTIHDMIKFIKPTVKVVGTGWVASAGITIYLAAEKENRFSLPNTRYMIHQPAGGVQGQSTEIEIEAKEIIRMRERINRLIAEATGQSYEQISKDTDRNFWLSVNEAKDYGIVNEIIENRDGLKMASWSHPQFEK
>4RYF_2
MNLIPTVIEQTSRGERAYDIYSRLLKDRIIMLGSAIDDNVANSIVSQLLFLDAQDPEKDIFLYINSPGGSISAGMAIYDTMNFVKADVQTIGMGMAASMGSFLLTAGANGKRFALPNAEIMIHQPLGGAQGQATEIEIAARHILKIKERMNTIMAEKTGQPYEVIARDTDRDNFMTAQEAKDYGLIDDIIINKSGLKGHHHHHH
```

I want to keep the sequence and previous line only if the sequence has a given length. For selecting only lines with that condition I use:

```
awk 'length($0) > 50 && length($0) <=800)' sample.txt
```

But how can I keep lines starting with > as well if this condition is met?

Comment: Are you looking for a bash implementation or a change to your awk script? In either case the answer is to delay the print of previous lines till you have the information to make a decision. Quick one-liner, btw, is to use egrep with -B 1 so it prints out the previous line if line matches.

Comment: could be with awk or bash. But I want to print both lines, not just the previous, would that work?

Comment: Regarding `could be with awk or bash` - no, it couldn't be with `bash` as that would involve writing a while-read loop which you should not do just to manipulate text, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yet another `awk` solution:

```
awk '/^>/ { header = $0; next } length > 50 && length <= 800 { print header ORS $0 }'
```

Comment: This isn't "another awk solution", it's **the** awk solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one-liner:

```
LANG=C grep -B1 '^.\{51,800\}$' < sample.txt
```

The command was really slow with LANG=en_US.UTF-8 that I set by default, so using LANG=C instead.

`man grep` tells you that '-B NUM' means ' Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines.'.

'^' means start of line
'.' means any character
'{51,800}' means we want between 51 and 800 of the previous thing
'$' means end of line.

Or in other words, we want to match lines that are between 51 and 800 characters, and print it and the previous line.

Comment: Thanks Allan could you explain a bit to me this regex? and what exactly does the flag B do?

Comment: Update answer with requested info.

Answer (score 3):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk -v RS='>' -F'\n' '
    length($2) > 50 && length($2) <= 800 {printf ">%s", $0}
' sample.txt
```

- Assigning `RS` to '>' tells `awk` to split the file on `>` into records,
  treating the header line and the sequence line in the same record.
- Assigning `FS` to '\n' splits the record to the header and
  sequence, each assigning `$1` to the header and `$2` to the sequence.
- As the leading `>` is chopped off as a delimiter, we need to prepend it
  when printing the matched records.

Answer (score 2):

A potential solution with AWK is:

```
awk '!/^>/ {next}; {getline s}; length(s) > 50 && length(s) <= 800 { print $0 "\n" s }' example.fasta
```

e.g. if `example.fasta` contains

```
>4RYF_1
WLSVNEAKDYGIVNEIIENRDGLKMASWSHPQFEK
>4RYF_2
MNLIPTVIEQTSRGERAYDIYSRLLKDRIIMLGSAIDDNVANSIVSQLLFLDAQDPEKDIFLYINSPGGSISAGMAIYDTMNFVKADVQTIGMGMAASMGSFLLTAGANGKRFALPNAEIMIHQPLGGAQGQATEIEIAARHILKIKERMNTIMAEKTGQPYEVIARDTDRDNFMTAQEAKDYGLIDDIIINKSGLKGHHHHHH
>1000_chars
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
```

It will only print

```
>4RYF_2
MNLIPTVIEQTSRGERAYDIYSRLLKDRIIMLGSAIDDNVANSIVSQLLFLDAQDPEKDIFLYINSPGGSISAGMAIYDTMNFVKADVQTIGMGMAASMGSFLLTAGANGKRFALPNAEIMIHQPLGGAQGQATEIEIAARHILKIKERMNTIMAEKTGQPYEVIARDTDRDNFMTAQEAKDYGLIDDIIINKSGLKGHHHHHH
```

### Edit

The method that I would recommend to better handle edge-cases is to use purpose-built bioinformatics software, e.g. [seqkit](https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/)

```
seqkit seq -m 50 -M 800 example.fasta
>4RYF_2
MNLIPTVIEQTSRGERAYDIYSRLLKDRIIMLGSAIDDNVANSIVSQLLFLDAQDPEKDI
FLYINSPGGSISAGMAIYDTMNFVKADVQTIGMGMAASMGSFLLTAGANGKRFALPNAEI
MIHQPLGGAQGQATEIEIAARHILKIKERMNTIMAEKTGQPYEVIARDTDRDNFMTAQEA
KDYGLIDDIIINKSGLKGHHHHHH
```

Comment: Thanks Jared for both suggestions! Just a naive question. Why do we need {next} if we're already specifying "for lines that don't begin with >"?

Comment: Don't use `getline` for this. It's fragile, not necessary, and makes it hard to add additional functionality later, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton! That is a very informative post and I can see the disadvantages to using getline here. There is no need to add additional functionality (this is a 'one and done' task in bioinformatics) but I see that @Thor's solution avoids any of the potential pitfalls. I still believe my 'seqkit' answer is the best solution to the problem due to edge cases e.g. if contigs contain strings of "N" (gaps) the seqkit program warns you and you can decide to include these or not when calculating length (`--gap-letters`) or you can remove/trim them using `--remove-gaps`.

Answer (score 1):

Is `perl` an option?

```
perl -nle '$prev && print if length() >50 and length() < 800 && print $prev; $prev = $_' input_file
```

`$prev` - Create a variable which will hold every line. When the length condition is met, and there has been a previous line `$prev`, then it prints the condition matched in `$prev` and prints the last line.

`$prev = $_` Assigns the current line to the `prev` line variable

---

If the upper limit `800` is not essential, could `sed` be an option?

```
$ sed -En '/>/ {N;/[a-zA-Z0-9]{50,}/p}' input_file
```

`/>/` - Match `>` and read into the pattern space

`N;` Run the condition on the next line after the match and append that to the pattern space also:

`{50,}` - If the length is 50 or more

`\1/p` - Return it and print

---

**Output**

```
>4RYF_2
MNLIPTVIEQTSRGERAYDIYSRLLKDRIIMLGSAIDDNVANSIVSQLLFLDAQDPEKDIFLYINSPGGSISAGMAIYDTMNFVKADVQTIGMGMAASMGSFLLTAGANGKRFALPNAEIMIHQPLGGAQGQATEIEIAARHILKIKERMNTIMAEKTGQPYEVIARDTDRDNFMTAQEAKDYGLIDDIIINKSGLKGHHHHHH
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS= '
{
  val=""
  delete arr
  while(match($0,/>[^\n]*\n*[^\n]*/)){
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    split(val,arr,"\n")
    if(length(arr[2])>50 && length(arr[2])<=800){
      print val
    }
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If only the next line should meet the length restrictions, you can match and store the line that starts with `>` in a variable, for example `previous`

Then for the next line, check for the length and if the previous line is not empty.

If is is not, print the previous and the current line.

At the end, set the previous variable to an empty string.

```
awk '{
  if (/^>/) {
    previous = $0
    next
  }
  if (length(previous) != 0 && length($0) > 50 && length($0) <= 800) {
    print previous ORS $0
  }
  previous=""
}' sample.txt
```

See an [AWK demo](https://ideone.com/2YtcTM)