# Combining info from several lines

Tags: xml, bash, awk, sed

I have an xml file which has entries sorted by one category. I'd like to generate an output which prints this category in the same line as (some) info in lines found part of that category.

My typical input generated via `grep -E "Kundschaft|continent" filename` looks like:

```
<landmarks continent="bagne" type="user">
<landmark type="3" x="595.21" y="-10981.47" title="~Ba-Nung Liangi (Kundschafter)"/>
<landmark type="3" x="943.54" y="-10365.21" title="Ba-Nung Liangi (Kundschafterin, Sapsammler)"/>
<landmarks continent="corrupted_moor" type="user"/>
<landmarks continent="fyros" type="user">
<landmark type="3" x="17106.73" y="-25706.46" title="Xymus Tindix (Kundschafter)"/>
<landmark type="3" x="17586.79" y="-25679.67" title="Apolus Abygrian (Kundschafter)"/>
<landmark type="3" x="17018.25" y="-25306.73" title="Ba'Reiliam Breggi (Kundschafter)"/>
```

From that I'd like to generate an output which quotes the continent followed by the title for each of the lines which contains a title element, e.g.:

```
bagne: ~Ba-Nung Liangi (Kundschafter)
bagne: Ba-Nung Liangi (Kundschafterin, Sapsammler)
fyros: Xymus tindix (Kundschafter)
fyros: Apolus Abygrian (Kundschafter)
fyros: Ba'Reiliam Breggi (Kundschafter)
```

I toyed around with awk a bit, but I don't properly manage to teach it to remember the continent and print it for each line which contains 'Kundschaft'.

I get somewhat a list which has the 'continent' as headings by using something like `grep -E "Kundschaft|continent" filename | awk -F "=" '{print $2 $5}'` yet that is not yet nicely readable. Questions and the answers like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69340094/keep-current-and-previous-line-only-if-current-line-fulfills-a-given-condition) or [here](https://www.funtoo.org/Awk_by_Example,_Part_2) suggest to me that it should be possible to teach awk how to treat this as multiline repeating the 'continent' heading, but no dice for me so far. The [man pages](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html) did not exactly help me along either.

Any pointers will be appreciated. If there is a non-awk solution (e.g. with sed) that shall be equally welcome.

Comment: XML need a XML parser, not regex, nor awk, sed grep... Use xmlstarlet, xmllint, xidel

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for you answer and comments. All answers solve it, and each has it's own advantages and disadvantages. So I upvoted each so far. sed solved my immediate problem fastest as I don't need to install anything, python is installed and I should have thought about using it to solve it myself as I use it quite a bit in other contexts, and with xidel I learnt about a new tool which will come in handy and is a nice and clean purpose-built solution. I still debate with myself which to accept as best.

Comment: I chose to accept the python solution as it integrates best for my particular purpose with the other parts of the data processing pipeline. As explained above, I'm glad for each answer, each is helpful, but can only accept one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using `python` and its' standard library, let `file.txt` content be

```
<landmarks continent="bagne" type="user">
<landmark type="3" x="595.21" y="-10981.47" title="~Ba-Nung Liangi (Kundschafter)"/>
<landmark type="3" x="943.54" y="-10365.21" title="Ba-Nung Liangi (Kundschafterin, Sapsammler)"/>
<landmarks continent="corrupted_moor" type="user"/>
<landmarks continent="fyros" type="user">
<landmark type="3" x="17106.73" y="-25706.46" title="Xymus Tindix (Kundschafter)"/>
<landmark type="3" x="17586.79" y="-25679.67" title="Apolus Abygrian (Kundschafter)"/>
<landmark type="3" x="17018.25" y="-25306.73" title="Ba'Reiliam Breggi (Kundschafter)"/>
```

then create `parse.py` file as follows

```
import xml.parsers.expat
common = {"continent": ""}
def start_element(name, attrs):
    if name=="landmarks":
        common["continent"] = attrs.get("continent", "")
    if name=="landmark":
        print(common["continent"] + ": " + attrs.get("title", ""))

p = xml.parsers.expat.ParserCreate()
p.StartElementHandler = start_element
with open("file.txt", "rb") as f:
    try:
        p.ParseFile(f)
    except xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError:
        pass
```

then

```
python parse.py
```

gives output

```
bagne: ~Ba-Nung Liangi (Kundschafter)
bagne: Ba-Nung Liangi (Kundschafterin, Sapsammler)
fyros: Xymus Tindix (Kundschafter)
fyros: Apolus Abygrian (Kundschafter)
fyros: Ba'Reiliam Breggi (Kundschafter)
```

*(tested in Python 3.8.10)*

Answer (score 3):

With [`xidel`](https://github.com/benibela/xidel),  using [`XPath`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/): (subset of [`XQuery`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/)'s [`XML`](https://www.w3.org/XML/)'s language) and `XQuery`:

```
xidel --xquery '
    for $node in //landmarks/landmark
        let $cont := $node/parent::landmarks/@continent
        let $text := $node/@title
    return concat($cont, ": ", $text)
' file
```

```
bagne: ~Ba-Nung Liangi (Kundschafter)
bagne: Ba-Nung Liangi (Kundschafterin, Sapsammler)
fyros: Xymus Tindix (Kundschafter)
fyros: Apolus Abygrian (Kundschafter)
fyros: Ba'Reiliam Breggi (Kundschafter)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just as @GillesQuénot suggested, I would recommend `xidel` for this task:

```bash
xidel --xpath '//landmark/string-join( (../@continent, @title), ": ")' filename
```

output:

```
bagne: ~Ba-Nung Liangi (Kundschafter)
bagne: Ba-Nung Liangi (Kundschafterin, Sapsammler)
fyros: Xymus Tindix (Kundschafter)
fyros: Apolus Abygrian (Kundschafter)
fyros: Ba'Reiliam Breggi (Kundschafter)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '/.*continent="([^"]*)".*/{s//\1/;h;d}
         s/.*title="([^"]*)".*/\1/;T;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2: \1/p' file
```

Extract the continent value and make a copy in the hold buffer.

Extract the title and combine it with the continent value from the hold buffer and format as required.

Comment: sed is not meant to parse XML, it's main purpose is line stream. This is just unreliable, not human readable and not maintenable. (if XML change a bit)

Comment: @GillesQuénot perhaps you are right. However the OP asked for a sed solution (amongst others) and given their inputs this provides the required outputs.

Comment: If someone ask you to shoot him with a gun, because of lake of knowledge, you will shoot him?

Comment: @GillesQuénot I feel your pain, my answer was not an act of belligerence.